# SSIS: SharePoint 2013 List adapters: Which ones can i Use

Tags: ssis, sharepoint-2013, sharepoint-list

Hi there I am currently trying to get data from a SharePoint list into an OLE Database,

My question is as follows: can i use the following Adapters for SharePoint 2013:

[CodePlex SharePoint Adapters](http://sqlsrvintegrationsrv.codeplex.com/releases/view/17652)

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can. Apart from the URL, I found that no other changes were required for the configuration when moving from Sharepoint 2010 to Sharepoint 2013.